# Parse HTML tags

Tags: php, mysql

I fetches from value from db like:

```
<p><img alt="" src="images/1.jpg" style="width: 2450px; height: 1054px;" /></p>
```

and wants to only get `src="images/1.jpg"` but don't know how. Please guide me

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the source, use a DOM Parser:

```php
// Construct a new DOMDocument with your fragment
$domDoc = new DOMDocument;
$domDoc->loadHTML( '<p><img src="images/1.jpg" style="width: 2450px;" /></p>' );

// Locate the first image the document
$img = $domDoc->getElementsByTagName( "img" )->item( 0 );

// Echo its src value
echo $img->attributes->getNamedItem( "src" )->nodeValue;
```

Results: http://codepad.org/oMXGK9Iu

Ideally you would ensure the image elements exist before accessing items #0. Likewise, you would ensure the attributes exist before just leaping out and grabbing them.

Further reading: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

If you just want to grab that particular portion of the text, you could use a simple regular expression:

```php
// Prep our html
$html = '<p><img src="images/1.jpg" style="width: 2450px;" /></p>';

// Look for the source string
preg_match( '/src=\".*?\"/', $html, $matches );

// If we found it, spit it out.
echo $matches ? $matches[0] : "No source";
```

Answer (score 0):

if `alt=""` is empty by default and style is `width: 2450px; height: 1054px;` by default you could use:

```
<?php
$str = '<p><img alt="" src="images/1.jpg" style="width: 2450px; height: 1054px;" /></p>';
$str = str_replace('<p><img alt="" src="','', $str);
$str = str_replace('" style="width: 2450px; height: 1054px;" /></p>','',$str);
echo $str; //Outputs: images/1.jpg
?>
```